# JavaScript xmlhttp read from feed

Tags: javascript, xml, feed

I'm trying to use javascript and read [from http://search.yahooapis.com/ WebSearchService /V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo &query=persimmon&results=2](http://search.yahooapis.com/%20WebSearchService%20/V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo%20&query=persimmon&results=2) using xmlhttp. I'm getting an error because it cannot read

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       url="http://search.yahooapis.com/ WebSearchService /V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo &query=persimmon&results=2";
       var xmlhttp = null;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
       {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          if ( typeof xmlhttp.overrideMimeType != 'undefined') 
          {
             xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
          }
       } 
       else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
       {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       } 
       else 
       {
          alert('Perhaps your browser does not support xmlhttprequests?');
       }

       xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
       xmlhttp.send(null);
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
       {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
           {
            alert("success");
           }
           else 
           {
            alert("failure");
           }
      };
</script>
```

Comment: There error is 'failure', the block in the else part alert("failure")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your web site is hosted on `search.yahooapis.com` you're probably encountering the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

This is causing your outgoing request to return with a `404` status code:

[image]

You should be using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) instead of `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>JavaScript file download</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function yahooApi(resp) {
         var scriptEl = document.getElementById("yahooApiJsonP");
         scriptEl.parentNode.removeChild(scriptEl);
         console.log(resp);
     }

     window.onload = function() {
         var scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
         scriptEl.id = "yahooApiJsonP";
         scriptEl.src = "http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?output=json&callback=yahooApi&appid=YahooDemo&query=persimmon&results=2";
         document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
     };
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p>This is a test</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

This will send the request, which will return a `200 OK` status:[image]

---

It also looks like [this service has been shut down](http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo%20&query=persimmon&results=2):

[image]